# Pyqt close unselected tab

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt, qtabwidget

So to close tabs I've been using the QTabWidget.currentWidget() to find the selected tab to close, but now when I click the close icon on a different tab, it closes the current tab because of how I have set this up

So how can I find the tab attached the the close button so I can close the correct tab?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please handle with [`void tabCloseRequested (int)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#tabCloseRequested) to get current index of widget has been request close. Next, find this widget with index by [`QWidget QTabWidget.widget (self, int index)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#widget) and delete it. Or, use [`QTabWidget.removeTab (self, int index)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) (But The page widget itself is not deleted).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomTabWidget (QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            self.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), 'Tab %d' % i)

    def closeTab (self, currentIndex):
        currentQWidget = self.widget(currentIndex)
        currentQWidget.deleteLater()
        self.removeTab(currentIndex)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTabWidget = QCustomTabWidget()
myQCustomTabWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it helped me spot some errors I had made too, got it working now, thanks a lot